# Retrofit and coroutines with the PokeApi don't work for me

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I try to make a recycler view with the name and picture of the pokemon, but it doesn't work, I don't understand why, the requests are not done because the pokemon list is never filled. I make a loop for calls because what I want is the name and picture of the pokemon, because when I ask for a list of pokemon objects only bring the name and the url of the complete object and is the best way that has occurred to me, I would appreciate if you can give me a hand, thank you very much.

**This is the code of my mainActivity:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    initRecycler()
    obtenerPokemons()

}


private fun initRecycler(){
    pokemonAdapter = PokemonAdapter(pokemons)
    linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    binding.recyclerpokemon.apply {
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        adapter = pokemonAdapter
    }

}


private fun obtenerPokemons() {
    for (i in 1..30)  {
        searchByName(i)
    }

    pokemonAdapter.setPokemons(pokemons)
}


private fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}

private fun searchByName(query:Int){
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val call = getRetrofit().create(PokemonService::class.java).getPokemon("pokemon/$query")
        val pokemonsResp = call.body()
        runOnUiThread {
            if(call.isSuccessful) {
                pokemons.add(pokemonsResp)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "No encuentro eso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

**This is the pokemon object code:**

```
data class Pokemon (
    @SerializedName("id"                       ) var id                     : Int,
    @SerializedName("name"                     ) var name                   : String,
    @SerializedName("sprites"                  ) var sprites                : Sprites,
    )
data class Sprites (
    @SerializedName("back_default"       ) var backDefault      : String,
    @SerializedName("front_default"      ) var frontDefault     : String,
    )
```

**And this is the code of my service:**

```
interface PokemonService {
    @GET
    suspend fun getPokemon(@Url url:String) : Response<Pokemon?>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `pokemonAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after `pokemons.add(pokemonsResp)`. `notifyDataSetChanged()` will update the recycler view with the new data.

Comment: Wow, I'm doing that in the adapter, after sending the whole list in the "obtenerPokemons" method, what you say worked, but why doesn't it work like I did?

Comment: you must be doing it in `setPokemons` function. That function is called only once and at that time, the list is empty, so there is no data to display. So when you add new data you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` again.

Comment: Why at that moment the list is empty, when it is executed after the loop ends it should be full, right?